# Switch from linux-virtual to linux-azure for Accelerated Networking support

Tags: 16.04, package-management, kernel, metapackages, azure

We have Azure VMs running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS that we would like to use the [Azure Accelerated Networking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli) feature on. The minimum kernel version needed is 4.11.0-1013, but currently with apt-get upgrade we can only get to 4.4.0-109-generic. Also `apt list --installed linux*` shows we are using the [linux-virtual](https://superuser.com/a/849748/26374) kernel package instead of the [linux-azure](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/09/21/microsoft-and-canonical-increase-velocity-with-azure-tailored-kernel/) kernel package.

Should we switch to the linux-azure kernel package and if so what are the steps for replacing linux-virtual with linux-azure? Currently lspci shows the Mellanox VF device is present but `ethtool -S eth0` returns "no stats available" (presumably due to the older kernel).

Answer (score 1):

The following worked to switch from the linux-virtual package to the linux-azure package:

```
sudo apt install linux-azure
sudo apt purge linux-virtual 
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

After a reboot we now see the updated kernel and stats for the Mellanox VF device:

```
uname -a
Linux MyVM 4.13.0-1005-azure #7-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:37:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ethtool -S eth0 | grep vf_
     vf_rx_packets: 510
     vf_rx_bytes: 721043
     vf_tx_packets: 892
     vf_tx_bytes: 200765
     vf_tx_dropped: 0
```